# SharePoint 2010 Hyperlink Document Edit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a hyperlink column within a list. The hyperlinks are going out to a document library within the same site. When I click on the link it prompts the file to be downloaded.  I want the prompt to edit the document instead. Is this possible without using designer? Thank you for your help its greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this behavior by making some settings in Central Administration.

**CA > Application Management > Manage Web Application > Select your web application and then select General settings from the Ribbon**

Navigate to **Browser File Handling**  section in the Genral settings and then Select Permissive radio button.

This will allow your documents to be open in a client application or Browser application instead of Downloading it.

Hope this helps

Thanks